# School project with this error: Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a project for school and I get this error for a non-render portion of my code.

```
fetchCharacterData = () => {
    var encodedURI = window.encodeURI(this.props.uri);
    return axios.get(encodedURI).then(response => {
        this.setState(() => {
            return {
                characterData: response.data
            };
        });
    });
};
```

It has a problem with the line that reads **this.setState(() => {** I tried the suggestions on the other questions and nothing seems to work with this line of code.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchCharacterData();
    console.log("MOUNT");
}

render() {
    console.log(this.state.characterData);
    if (this.state.characterData.length === 0) {
       return <div>Failed to fetch data from server</div>;
    }
    const characters = this.state.characterData.map(character => {
       return <div key={character.name}><em>: {character.name}</em>: {character.class} </div>
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the contents of your `render` function? That's where this error would be caused.

Comment: Added it above.

Comment: You are creating that `characters` array, but you are indeed not `return`ing anything from the `render` method on that path.

Comment: According to my console, it's pulling the information that is supposed to be displayed. I'm not sure what to change as this is code given by the school that they claim to work.

Comment: You don’t return the results of the map.

Comment: Does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix it? I'm following along in a lesson,this is the code we're given and told it should work...I'll double check it also.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return something in your render function - the error is unrelated to the code you pasted.

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {

    // ...

    fetchCharacterData = () => {
        var encodedURI = window.encodeURI(this.props.uri);
        return axios.get(encodedURI).then(response => {
            this.setState(() => {
                return {
                    characterData: response.data
                };
            });
        });
    };

    // ...

    // It's this part causing the error.
    // It either returns nothing, or doesn't exist.
    render() {
        return <div>Your page content</div> // or return null
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you had a look through the React docs? They're honestly some of the best docs out there - I think they'll help you figure out what the render method does and why it's required: https://reactjs.org/

Answer (score 2):

try adjust your render function like this.

```
render() {
    if (this.state.characterData.length === 0) {
       return <div>Failed to fetch data from server</div>;
    }
    const characters = this.state.characterData.map(character => {
       return <div key={character.name}><em>: {character.name}</em>: {character.class} </div>
    });
    /******************/
    return characters;
    /******************/
}
```